# Finding the most tree-like hierarchy that explains the data

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, pandas, machine-learning

Consider the following dataframe:

```
      A  B  C
1    A1 B1 C1
2    A2 B2 C2
3    A3 B1 C1
4    A1 B1 C2
5    A2 B1 C1
6    A1 B4 C2
```

where `A`, `B` and `C` represent attributes. I am hoping to infer the **most likely** hierarchical structure between `A`, `B` and `C`. By this, I mean finding the ordering of `{A,B,C}` that yields a hierarchy with the least number of nodes with more than one parent.

For example, let's consider one hierarchical possibility:

```
A->B->C
```

We note that it has nodes with several parents.  To see this, we observe that `A1` co-occurs with `B1` **and** `B4` in the combinations `A1 B1 C1` and `A1 B4 C1`. However, `A3` **also** co-occurs with `B1` in row `3`, with `A3 B1 C1`.

In other words, only focusing on this part of the graph, if we assume the hierarchy `A->B->C`, we would have a node `B1` with two parents:

[image]

The question is thus, given an arbitrary dataframe like the one above, how can I find the hierarchical ordering of the columns that yields the least number of nodes with more than one parent?

### Notes:

There are more variants to this problem, e.g.

1. Finding the hierarchy with the least number of (extra) multi-parent edges
2. Finding the hierarchy with the least total number of edges

Solving any of these variants would be great.

Comment: Those aren't cycles. It's just a node `B1` with more than one parent.

Comment: @cheper Fair enough. There are certainly several variants of the "most treel-like" problem that one could formulate (e.g. `least number of nodes with more than one parent`, or `least number of parent-to-child edges`). I reworded the OP to correct that, and choose the one that I think captures the problem I have at hand best.

Answer (score 2):

Here is undirected graph with your dataframe. Edge (x,y) means that there was some data line such that both x,y was mentioned.

For example - last line "A1,B4,C2" added edges (A1,B4), (B4,C2), (A1,C2)

[image]

Now it's possible to sort A,B,C according to your wishes.

> Finding the hierarchy with the least number of (extra) multi-parent edges

We can bruteforce all arrangements (it's quite fast for [N = 8..10](http://oeis.org/A000522)) and find the cheapest (smallest, shortest) one. Edge costs in such tree (below) can be computed by graph shown above.

[image]

Mb there can be some greedy approach, smth like "Choose the cheapest on current step", I'm not sure right now, but I'm pretty sure that this representation of problem is prespective.

Comment: Thanks. How did you get the second graph from the first one? (i.e. algorithmically).

Comment: @user815423426 I didn't. The second graph is just a representation of problem "bruteforce all possible arrangements (ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA)". But costs (number of multi-parent edges) of edges should be computed by first graph (to choose the best arrangement).